# Range space, Null space related problem

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]
In this I am not getting any idea how to proceed. Please suggest something.

Comment: Have you tried taking some examples?

Comment: yes , I tried with some matrix but found none are correct. This question can have multiple options correct.

Comment: If you found an example where $A\cup B\neq B$ then you know that (a) is false.  Are you saying you found examples where each of them are false?  Then all of them are false... which examples did you find and which of the options did they disprove?

Comment: (a) is equivalent to saying $A\subset B$, but this is pretty obvious. (b) also is equivalent to $A\subset B$ which then is equivalent to (a).

Comment: I took matrix[ 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1;0 0 0]  row-wise of order 3, and got A= <(1 0 0)>; B=<(0 1 0), (0 0 1)> and C= <(0 0 1)>

Comment: So from here I am feeling none are correct! Please help.

Comment: You calculated both $B$ and $C$ incorrectly for your example.

Comment: Yes , is it B=<(1 0 0), (0 1 0)> and C= <(1 0 0)>? Then a,b, c are correct. Am I right?

Comment: In that **very specific** example, they are true, but are they **always** true?  That requires a more general proof.  All that your example showed is that (d) is sometimes false.

Comment: Ok, i think a, b is true always. I took a 5 order matrix with two Jordan blocks, one of order 3 like above and another of order 2. Then I found option a,b are correct for this but option c is not. But what will be a prove for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example from your comments in closer detail,

$T=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}~~~T^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}~~~T^3=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

We have $A=R(T^2)=span\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$

We have $B=N(T^2)=span\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$

We have $C=N(T) = span\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$

With this example, we do actually have $A\cup B=B, A\cap B=A$ and $A\cap C=C$.  The *only* one of the four options that this example proves is false is the fourth one, $A\cup B\subseteq C$.

---

Let us approach more analytically instead of via examples.  Suppose $T^3=0$ and $T^2\neq 0$ (*i.e. nilpotency of rank 3*).  This tells us a few things, most importantly that $R(T^2)\subseteq N(T)$ and that $R(T)\subseteq N(T^2)$.

(*The proofs should be straightforward.  Suppose $x\in R(T^2)$, then there exists a $y$ such that $x=T^2y$.  Then $Tx=T(T^2y)=T^3y=0y=0$ so $x\in N(T)$.  Similarly for the other*)

We also know that $N(T)\subseteq N(T^2)$ and $R(T^2)\subseteq R(T)$

(*Again, the proofs are straightforward.  Suppose $x\in N(T)$.  Then $Tx=0$.  This implies that $T^2x = T(Tx)=T(0)=0$ so $x\in N(T^2)$, similarly for the other*)

Using all of this information together, we have that $R(T^2)\subseteq N(T)\subseteq N(T^2)$ implying that in fact the first two lines are in fact always true statements.

---

For the third statement: we ask if $A\cap C=C$, that is if $R(T^2)\cap N(T)=N(T)$.  We learned before that $R(T^2)\subseteq N(T)$ so we know that $R(T^2)\cap N(T)=R(T^2)$... this is then in essence asking whether or not $N(T)\subseteq R(T^2)$.  You should immediately doubt this.  Does there exist a transformation where the nullspace of $T$ is larger than the range of $T^2$?  We'll have a hard time finding one using just $3\times 3$ matrices, but if we go just one size up, we should be fine.

> Consider $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

$~$

> As a fun aside question, try proving that for $V$ a specifically three-dimensional vector space that in fact $N(T)$ must **equal** $R(T^2)$ for a linear transformation $T$ where $T^3=0$ but $T^2\neq 0$.  Hint for that, consider the possible dimensions of each space and the rank-nullity theorem.